# Integration SAS to Databricks

Tags: configuration, sas, connection, databricks, saspy

I am trying to work in SAS with python (using saspy) in Databricks. I need to do configuration to connected to remote machine with SSH . I dont have any idea how to config sascfg_personal.py.

Could you please help me what information I need from SAS machine to do this configuration.

I've had a look at this page: https://sassoftware.github.io/saspy/configuration.html
and find I need to go head with SSH.

I've installed saspy under databricks cluster and it is already ready to use.

Just I need to do some configuration to connect to SAS from Databricks

Thanks
Mali